# How to create pre-configured kernel boot parameters in Debian Installer

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I want to have an installer with custom boot parameters. This is so as not to have to enter them manually each time, for I want to use the installer for multiple installs.

Comment: Isn't [preseeding](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed) what you want? Please explain why the various methods described in the [installation manual](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apb.html.en) aren't suitable for you.

Comment: I was actually not aware you could do this via preseeding

Comment: @FerencWágner upon taking a closer look, the option I found with preseeding applies to the installed system, not the installer.

Comment: Right, and I'm still unsure what you want. Passing arguments to the installer *kernel* is only possible by adjusting your boot method, about which we don't know a thing. For everything else, preseeding should work.

Comment: Rephrasing: I want to change the default kernel boot parameters when you boot into the installer. By default I mean whatever is used when you hit enter on the boot prompt.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a CD/DVD installer, you have to remaster the installer image with modified kernel parameters in its boot loader configuration. For BIOS (not UEFI) boot on a stretch installer ISO the default boot option is described in `isolinux/gtk.cfg`. Change the `append` line to your liking, then build a new ISO as described at https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CD.